# Rails form_for only change controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to tell `form_for` to use a different controller **without** affecting the action.

I know how to change the URL like

```
form_for @car, url: { controller: 'admin/cars' }
```

but this will also change the action.

Is there any way I can use a different controller with `form_for` without affecting the automatic choosing of the action?

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the action like this and could pass the controller name as a variable:

```
form_for @car, url: { controller: @controller_name, action: "your_action" }
```

Comment: Of course. But my controller is named `cars` and not admin and I don’t want to specify an action. `admin/cars` means "controller cars of namespace admin". My question, however, was: How do I tell `form_for` to keep choosing the right action but use a different controller.

Comment: You could set a var in your controller for the controller name that sets this perhaps? Amended my answer to reflect this.

Comment: No, no. The name of the controller is always the same and I must provide it. But the action needs to be chosen by form_for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select action in routes, maybe this is helpful for you;

```
form_for @car, url: { cars_path }
```

in your routes file ;

```
post '/cars', to: 'cars#action_whatever_you_want'
```